# Exchange環境下でユーザ自身のメールアドレスを取得したい

Tags: vba

VBAで簡単なサインアップフォームを作ろうとしています。ワンクリックでユーザ（クリックした人）のメールアドレスをワークシートに記入するだけ、だと思っていたら、ユーザ名を抽出する方法や受け取ったメールの送信者のアドレスとかはちょろちょろ見つかるんですが、自分自身のメールアドレスとなると以外に情報がないのです・・・

自分のメアドくらい自分で入れさせろよ、というご意見もあろうかと思いますが、なるべくユーザのステップを減らしたい＆タイプミスを防ぎたい、という理由でして・・・

Comment: これらの記事が参考になりそうです。[How to get the email address of the current logged-in user?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26519325/9014308), [MS Access / Outlook 2010 - how to choose which account to send email from?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17977035/9014308), [choose account in outlook when send mail via excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49295235/9014308)

Comment: ドンピシャでした！ありがとうございました！